# On The Subject of Black Holes

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

<sup>(This is part of a series of puzzles written for [Timwi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1480/timwi?tab=profile) for a Secret Santa puzzle exchange, themed around various custom modules for the game *Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes*. No KTaNE knowledge is necessary for any of these puzzles except the final meta; each puzzle resolves to a single word or short phrase.)</sup>

---

## On The Subject of Black Holes

[image]

```
CLOCKWISE
1   Update
2   Goliath, perhaps
3   Upset, as a baby
4   Handles (a difficult situation)
5   Will's counterpart?
6   Method of skipping an intended path
7   District of a city
8   Dogs that may be "great"
9   Person in a club
10  Famed video game protagonist
11  One of the zodiac signs
12  Not particularly enjoying
13  ___bomb (mixed drink with Red Bull)
14  Go over once more
15  Extra-difficult level in Celeste
16  Capture
17  Rolled up some hay
18  Embankment made to prevent flooding
19  Profession associated with either cylindrical or conical hats
20  Jackal or fox, perhaps

COUNTERCLOCKWISE
1   Went berserk
2   Wish-granter of lore
3   Like some duties
4   Pattern of weaved strands
5   Actors Connery and Bean, for two
6   One component of a ritual, maybe
7   Swindler (with loans or cards, say)
8   Fights to the death
9   Dipper's twin sister
10  Lists of items
11  Xbox enthusiast, perhaps
12  Medicinal plants
13  Actor/comedian Foxx
14  Item that may be written with / or :
15  Kick off
16  Colorless
17  Prickly plant that is home to a rabbit in folklore
18  Prepares for cooking by adding bacon strips
19  Gamecube crossover game involving 10-CW
20  Gives in to pressure
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Eyebright

Here is the completed grid

> [image]

Reasoning

> Some of the answers to the clockwise clues are six letters long instead of five and these extend into the middle black shape. I've highlighted the additional letters in red and, reading clockwise, they spell out EYEBRIGHT.

Comment: The answer you currently have is incorrect. You're missing some letters.

Comment: @Deusovi Yep, thanks, completely missed two clues, updated now.

Comment: (Start at the big gap; other than that, your answer is correct.)